# Почему не отправляется почта в Debian8?

Tags: debian

Командой

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

выполнил настройку.

После этого в консоли пишу

```
echo "Test text" | mail -s "Test title" my-email@gmail.com
```

но ничего не приходит.

Что-то еще нужно настроить?

2018-05-01 12:38:08 1fD2mb-00010o-Ar == kelton@kelton.com.ua R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (110): Connection timed out

2018-05-01 12:38:08 1fD2mb-00010o-Ar == scansub@kelton.com.ua R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (110): Connection timed out

2018-05-01 12:38:09 1fDQw5-0002PZ-N7 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2607:f8b0:4001:c20::1b] Network is unreachable

2018-05-01 12:38:09 1fDQw5-0002PZ-N7 == my-email@gmail.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (101): Network is unreachable

2018-05-01 12:38:09 End queue run: pid=10590

2018-05-01 12:38:28 1fDRjw-0002mu-Bp <= sergey@debian.xxxx U=sergey P=local S=394

2018-05-01 12:38:28 1fDRjw-0002mu-Bp == my-email@gmail.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (-53): retry time not reached for any host

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что в логах? Что в спаме?

Comment: см. `/var/log/exim4/mainlog`

Comment: @alexander barakin Логи выложил

Comment: @sanmai В спаме нету

Comment: в приведённых строках нет ничего про `my-gmail@example.com`

Comment: Не, не, команда echo "Test text" | mail -s "Test title" my-email@gmail.com

Comment: *[2607:f8b0:4001:c20::1b] Network is unreachable* — либо настройте ipv6, либо отключите.

Comment: А как отключить?

Comment: Задайте вопрос про это или используйте поиск. Лучше второе.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianIPv6#How_to_turn_off_IPv6

Answer (score 0):

> alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2607:f8b0:4001:c20::1b] Network is unreachable

доменное имя `alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com` (как и большинство других имён, принадлежащих *google*) резолвится как в ipv4, так и в ipv6-адреса.

в вашем компьютере ipv6 не функционирует.

вам следует либо [настроить ipv6](https://version6.ru/ways), либо [отключить этот протокол вовсе](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianIPv6#How_to_turn_off_IPv6).

Comment: После выяснения, оказалось-таки, что у провайдера закрыт 25-й порт. Сказали подключаться по SMTP. Дали сервер и порт. Как мне теперь настроить Debian в новых реалиях?

Comment: как и обычно: `dpkg-reconfigure`. то, что вам «дали», называется *smarthhost*.

Comment: Какой именно выбирать?

Comment: На ноуте настроил, почта приходить стала, но на рабочем по-прежнему не работает, что-то начудил с ip6. Вроде по памяти восстановил, но не приходит, не поможете?

Comment: Все, получилось. Спасибо!